# iTunes RSS Feed always returns duration=30000

Tags: ios, rss, itunes

I'm using the following [link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topsongs/limit=10/explicit=true/json) in order to get top 10 songs from iTunes for USA:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topsongs/limit=10/explicit=true/json
```

I need to have every song's duration, but I always receive value **30000** for duration:

```
"im:duration": {
"label": "30000"
}
```

What does it mean, and is there a way to get the right duration value? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this [online time calculator](http://www.unitarium.com/time-calculator) and the sum of all songs's duration is 37.97 minutes; Checking a song sample *Setting the World on Fire (with P!nk)*.

I think that `30000` is just the value of the **sample duration**. The RSS link that you provided doesn't contain the duration of the song(s) *as is shown in the ITunes website*.

If you really need the *real* duration of the songs, you have to use another way of get this information.

---

I tried use "[The Widget Builder](https://widgets.itunes.apple.com/builder/)" and select "ITunes Search".

Here, when you use the widget for search a song (example: type *dile*), if you debug in the "Network" tab, you will get this URL:

https://itunes.apple.com/search?limit=20&country=us&media=music&entity=song&term=dile&callback=jQuery183020996109495104198_1478097762593&_=1478097910165

The results are:

```
{
    "wrapperType": "track",
    "kind": "song",
    "artistId": 65630139,
    "collectionId": 76542569,
    "trackId": 76542586,
    "artistName": "Don Omar",
    "collectionName": "The Last Don",
    "trackName": "Dile",
    "collectionCensoredName": "The Last Don",
    "trackCensoredName": "Dile",
    "artistViewUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/don-omar/id65630139?uo=4",
    "collectionViewUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/dile/id76542569?i=76542586&uo=4",
    "trackViewUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/dile/id76542569?i=76542586&uo=4",
    "previewUrl": "http://a1801.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/136/Music7/v4/49/06/fe/4906fee2-16c0-9e99-64e9-e2d39c58b2b5/mzaf_6968581882856624700.plus.aac.p.m4a",
    "artworkUrl30": "http://is4.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music5/v4/d3/b3/6c/d3b36c67-3b50-f55e-df74-9febe37c80f9/source/30x30bb.jpg",
    "artworkUrl60": "http://is4.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music5/v4/d3/b3/6c/d3b36c67-3b50-f55e-df74-9febe37c80f9/source/60x60bb.jpg",
    "artworkUrl100": "http://is4.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music5/v4/d3/b3/6c/d3b36c67-3b50-f55e-df74-9febe37c80f9/source/100x100bb.jpg",
    "collectionPrice": 9.99,
    "trackPrice": 1.29,
    "releaseDate": "2003-06-17T07:00:00Z",
    "collectionExplicitness": "notExplicit",
    "trackExplicitness": "notExplicit",
    "discCount": 1,
    "discNumber": 1,
    "trackCount": 15,
    "trackNumber": 4,
    "trackTimeMillis": 204600,
    "country": "USA",
    "currency": "USD",
    "primaryGenreName": "Latin Urban",
    "isStreamable": true
}
```

There, you get the `trackTimeMillis` property.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you.